# Custom HTTP headers in Fetch API react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, http, fetch

An API I am trying to call need some custom headers like this

```
'aa11': 'value1'
'bb22': 'value2'
```

In postman, I call like this and it is working.
[image]

I need to call that API from my react native app so I searched at internet how to add custom headers in fetch and I tried like this.

```
fetch('www.api.com', {headers: {'aa11': 'value1', 'bb22': 'vaule2'}}).then(res => res.json()).then(result => console.log(result))
```

But it is not working. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for a few days, I found out the answer. I need to add this in headers.

```
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
```